# Navigation property is not being created in run time Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a Quest and QuestTemplate class like below

```
public class Quest{

    public int ID {get;set;}

    public virtual QuestTemplate QuestTemplate {get;set;}

    public string Name{get;set;}
}

public class QuestTemplate{

    public int ID {get;set;}

    public QuestTemplate QuestTemplate {get;set;}

    public string Name{get;set;}

    public virtual Quest Quest{get;set;}
}
```

I create Quest and QuestTemplate like below in runtime

```
Quest q = new Quest();
q.Name = "Foo";
q.QuestTemplate = new QuestTemplate();
q.QuestTemplate.Name = "Bar";

context.Quests.Add(q);
context.SaveChanges();
```

It adds quest object and quest template object into related tables (Quests, QuestTemplates in this example). However the problem is that the Quest_ID column of quest template object in table is not set with quest object's ID. Instead, it remains null. How can I resolve this problem?

P.S: I'm using EF5 with code first.

Best regards,

Kemal

Comment: Do you override database default EF mappings configuration?

Comment: nop i did not do anything special... I have just enabled cascade with  modelBuilder.Entity<Quest>().HasRequired(e => e.QuestTemplate).WithRequiredPrincipal().WillCascadeOnDelete(true); OnModelCreating method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowhere in the code did you specify the `QuestTemplate` applies to the `Quest` object. The following code should work:

```
Quest q = new Quest();
q.Name = "Foo";

QuestTemplate qt = new QuestTemplate();
qt.QuestTemplate.Name = "Bar";
qt.Quest = q;

q.QuestTemplate = qt;

context.Quests.Add(q);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Or you can map a one-to-one relationship.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Quest >()
    .HasRequred(q => q.QuestTemplate)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

**Edit**

Looked at this tonight and the reason for the relation isn't mapping is in regards to the FK name. If you specify the FK in the fluent mapping, the relationship works as expected. Also, this type of 1-to-1 relationship requires either `Quest` or `QuestTemplate` be loaded first before the other (since it's a required field) I randomly chose `QuestTemplate` below:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Quest> Quests { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Quest>()
            .HasOptional(q => q.QuestTemplate)
            .WithRequired(qt => qt.Quest)
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("QuestId"));
    }
}

public class Quest
{
    public int QuestId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestTemplate QuestTemplate { get; set; }
}

public class QuestTemplate
{
    public int QuestTemplateId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Quest Quest { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
        {
            Quest q = new Quest { Name = "Bar" };
            q.QuestTemplate = new QuestTemplate { Name = "Foo" };
            db.Quests.Add(q);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I believe it has something to do with the section titled `Foreign Keys` [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/06/01/conventions-for-code-first.aspx), but I'm still not clear on why this is. I have other relationships configured exactly the same way without identifying the FK.

Comment: If you look at my comment , I have already done mapping one-to-one relationship on my modelbuilder :(

Comment: Did you implement the first part of the solution?

Comment: Yes when I do that it works. But what I didnt understand is that shouldn't it be mapped automatically in runtime ?